# Java: Compare XPath structure

Tags: java, xml, xpath, functional-testing

I am writing some functional tests that should compare the XML *structure* of two XML documents. This means that the tag order and naming is improtant, while the tag content is irrelevant.

For example, the following calls:

Call 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Call 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Have the same tag structure, but:

Call 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Is different, because it has a `<year>` tag after `<author>`, and calls 1 and 2 lack that tag.

**What's the Java way to compare XML Structures?**

Comment: what you mean by compare? Print differences?

Comment: Printing the differences would be a benefit, but even printing the first different node would be fine.

Comment: I have done an XML compare process (in Java) before (sorry, can't share the code). It is not trivial. For a structure like what you show, a relatively simple loop can be used for each element. The problems I have had are mostly performance, and how to **show** the differences. IF you want a more generic compare, then you should look at the LCS algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Thanks @rolfl, it's a useful piece of info. I don't care about performance, and I don't need a fancy diff-like viewer. If I can't find a ready-made solution, I might just write one and publish it on github

Comment: do you have scheme for those xmls? Could help u a lot.

Comment: Nope. The schema might change, but I don't want to update my tests whenever that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a class that flattens the XML and provides a human-readable String for comparison.

For my comparison purpose, I create two `XPathFlattener` objects, and compare their `toString()` representation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class XPathFlattener {

    private Node root;

    public XPathFlattener(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    /**
     * Flattens a XPath tree to a list of nodes, in pre-order traversal.
     */
    public List<Node> flatten() {
        List<Node> nodes = flattenTreeToList(this.root, new ArrayList<Node>());
        return nodes; 
    }

    /**
     * Flattens a XPath tree to a list of Strings, each representing the name
     * of the node, but not its contents. 
     * The list is created using pre-order traversal.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        List<String> nodesStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node n:this.flatten()) {
            nodesStrings.add(stringRepresentation(n));
        }
        return StringUtils.join(nodesStrings, ", ");
    }

    /**
     * Recursively flattens a Node tree to a list, in pre-order traversal.
     * @param node
     * @param nodes
     * @return
     */
    private static List<Node> flattenTreeToList(Node node, List<Node> nodes) {
        nodes.add(node);
        for (int i=0; i< node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            Node childNode = node.getChildNodes().item(i);
            flattenTreeToList(childNode, nodes);
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    /**
     * A String representation of the node structure, without its contents.
     * @param node
     * @return
     */
    private static String stringRepresentation(Node node) {
        return String.format("[%s, (type %d)]", node.getNodeName(), node.getNodeType());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke a simple XSLT transformation on both documents which strips out all the text nodes and attribute content, and then call XPath deep-equal() on the two results.

Comment: Could you provide a link please?

Comment: A Java code example would be very helpful. I'm currently exploring Apache Xalan, and I'm not sure that's the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I answer questions here either because they are interesting or because they can be answered in a few seconds, and this one doesn't fall into either category.

Comment: My suggestion of using deep-equal() requires XSLT 2.0, which is not supported by Xalan; you want to use Saxon for that.